# How to get the app port when launching an app in Deis?

Tags: deis

I'm using a Dockerfile to deploy my app. I have an EXPOSE directive with port 4432.

When I deploy using `git push deis master` or `deis pull my-docker-image` days returns a success message showing the domain name for my app (`deis logs` also shows the service running just fine). However, when use this domain name and navigate to a valid path the browser seems to hang.

I read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/deis-users/Z2bTl6JLYIk) the Deis uses `-P` behind the scenes, so my question **is how do I get the port on which my app is running?**

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Deis automagically maps to port 80, it wasn't working for me for unrelated reasons (bug somewhere else)